# Как перемещать объект по экрану мышью и сохранить его последнее положение после обновления?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Мой объект

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>ball</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="obj">
<img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballgreen.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Напишите, пожалуйста, код

Comment: у каждого пользователя свое местоположение?

Comment: Stranger in the Q, Да

Comment: если у пользователя своё местоположение то необходимо хранить данные в бд, и при проверки авторизации попутно брать эти данные. Чтобы сохранить эти данные и отправить, необходимо использовать AJAX и отправлять данные либо после какой-то неактивности человека после перетаскивании, либо чтобы он подтверждал сохранение через кнопку. Если это какая-то игра, можно попробовать на js открыть сокет и вписывать данные туда.

Comment: можно записывать его координаты в localstorage, а при загрузке их доставать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете записывать координаты в localStorage, а при загрузке их доставать и использовать как угодно.В вашем случае задавать положение блоку.

```
setCoordinate();
function setCoordinate() {
    let coordinate = {};

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
        coordinate.xcord = event.pageX;
        coordinate.ycord = event.pageY;

        // Пишем координаты
        localStorage.setItem("userCords", JSON.stringify(coordinate));
    }
}
```

После загрузки страницы достаем координаты

```
let storageCoordinate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userCords"));
    console.log(storageCoordinate);
});
```

Подробнее о localStorage можно прочесть тут

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp