# Как сохранить изменения расположения объектов? Чтобы после обновления страницы объекты не возвращались в исходное положение

Tags: javascript, php, html

Помогите, пожалуйста, с кодом

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Move</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var canvas, ctx, num = 0;
        var box = [];
        var dragok = false;
        var startX;
        var startY;
        var offsetX = 10;
        var offsetY = 10;

        function main() {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = 300;
            canvas.height = 300;
            canvas.style.background = "#444444";
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            box.push({
                x: 30,
                y: 100,
                z: 0,
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                fill: "#4CFF00",
                isDragging: false,
            });
            box.push({
                x: 70,
                y: 100,
                z: 1,
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                fill: "#ff550d",
                isDragging: false
            });
            box.push({
                x: 110,
                y: 100,
                z: 2,
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                fill: "#FFE347",
                isDragging: false
            });
            box.push({
                x: 150,
                y: 100,
                z: 3,
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                fill: "#23FFCB",
                isDragging: false
            });
            draw();

            canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
            canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
            canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
        }

        function myMove(e) {
            if (dragok) {
                var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
                var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

                var dx = mx - startX;
                var dy = my - startY;

                for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
                    if (box[i].isDragging == true) {
                        box[i].x += dx;
                        box[i].y += dy;
                    }
                }
                draw();
                startX = mx;
                startY = my;
            }
        }

        function myUp(e) {
            dragok = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
                box[i].isDragging = false;
            }
        }

        function myDown(e) {

            var mx = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
            var my = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

            dragok = true;
            var group = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {

                if (mx > box[i].x && mx < box[i].x + box[i].width && my > box[i].y && my < box[i].y + box[i].height) {
                    group.push(box[i]);
                }
            }

            if (group.length === 1)
            {
                group[0].isDragging = true;
            }
            else if (group.length >= 2)
            {
                var maxZ = group[0].z;
                var b = group[0];

                for (var i = 1; i < group.length; i++)
                {
                    if (maxZ < group[i].z)
                    {
                        maxZ = group[i].z;
                        b = group[i];
                    }
                }
                b.isDragging = true;
            }

            startX = mx;
            startY = my;
        }

        function rect(r) {
            ctx.fillStyle = r.fill;
            ctx.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
        }

        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
                rect(box[i]);
            }
        }
        main();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: нужно все данные сохранять в localstorage

Comment: Ваш однофамилец тоже этим интересуется https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/974481

Comment: не перезагружать страницу

Comment: Однофамилец уже и ответ нашел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/974460